# Prestashop multistore search index error

Tags: indexing, prestashop, multistore

I'm using prestashop 1.5 in a multistore configuration in which no products are shared and the problem is when I add / update a product is indexed for all stores. I have many references and search_index table is giant ...

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need to index the product only in his shop to reduce the size of search_index table

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 24 (36482133 total, Query took 0.0003 seconds.)
I have others tables even bigger, but the index table makes slows the search and the web services